# Mixing typenames and values with template pack expansion

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is it possible to mix typenames and values when using template pack expansion?

For instance, is it possible to do something like the Bar function below?

```
template <typename T> class A
{
public:
    void Foo()
    {
        printf( "A.Foo()\n" );
    }
};

template <typename T, int x> class B
{
public:
    void Foo()
    {
        printf( "B.Foo() with x = %d\n", x );
    }
};

template <typename ClassType, typename... SubVals>
void Bar( ClassType<SubVals...> obj )
{
    obj.Foo();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A<int> a;
    B<float, 3> b;

    Bar<int>( a ); // This is allowed by the compiler
    Bar<float, 3>( b ); // Compiler yells at this, though.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a gut reaction, I would say no, it's not allowed. By doing `typename...` you are implying that the pack that follows is composed of types.

Comment: What you probably want to do is have a non-type parameter pack: `template<typename ClassType, ClassType... SubVals> void Bar(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with this by accepting a non-type parameter pack of `int`, and letting the compiler deduce a third template argument for the class templated on a type and zero or more `int` values.

```
template<typename T, int... Vals, template<typename, int...> class C> 
void Bar(C<T, Vals...> obj)
{
    obj.Foo();
}
```

Can be called with explicit template arguments like in your example:

```
A<int> a;
B<float, 3> b;
C<double, 1, 2, 3> c;

// explicit template args
Bar<int>(a);
Bar<float, 3>(b);
Bar<double, 1, 2, 3>(c);
```

Or deduced ones:

```
// deduced ones
Bar(a);
Bar(b);
Bar(c);
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36c7c54cf5dbceff) (Note I left in an earlier working prototype that may be easier to follow for some).